# Non-recursive way to list files in directory and subdirectories without using stack/queue

Tags: algorithm, recursion, stack, queue

During an interview, I was asked to list the names of files in a directory and its subdirectories¹ without using neither recursion, nor stack or queue.

Since the only non-recursive way I know uses a stack, I was unable to answer this question.

The interviewer explained the solution, but I was unable to understand it. The only thing I remember is that it involved two methods instead of one.

What is this approach which allows listing files in a directory and its subdirectories with no recursion and no stack or queue?

---

<sup>¹ The solution is language agnostic. The list of subdirectories is provided by a `ListDirectories(string directoryPath)` method, and the files - by `ListFiles(string directoryPath)`. We don't know in advance the depth of subdirectories.</sup>

Comment: Are you allowed to use an ADT that imposes a different order (or no order) on elements being added / removed than FIFO or LIFO? For example, would you be allowed to use a heap which stores all unexplored folder sorted by name? Strictly speaking, this is neither a stack nor a queue.

Comment: You could buid a tree of the folders that you are exploring. You can use a flag on each node to mark the node as visited or not.

Comment: @vitalik: You can view a tree as just a fancier version of a queue/list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a depth-first search note that the current path essentially serves as a stack. Listing names in a depth-first manner, proceed like you would expect but don't bother recording a stack... When you're done listing files in a directory, you can 'pop' the stack by noting what the last directory was that you were in and then continue from that point in the parent directory.

Comment: thanks - i have been wondering what was meant here all morning...  have to add that imo this is a pretty lame interview question.  it's not about understanding anything important - just playing "hide the stack"...  but maybe i am just bitter for not seeing this answer.

Comment: It's a semi-clever question in my opinion, but I agree that the wording leaves much to be desired because it's very imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (pseudocode):

```
baseDirectory = "/usr"
list = [baseDirectory] // list of directories to traversal
files = []
while (list not empty) {
  d = list.getFirst(); // get directory
  directories = ListDirectories(d);
  files.add(ListFiles(d)); // add all files from current directory
  list.add(directories); //add all directories from current directory to traversal
  list.remove(d); // remove traversed dir
}
```

We using just lists :) But this approach very similar to stack/queue solution

Comment: You are using a queue. It doesn't matter if you call it a list. You are using the list as a queue. You are dequeuing items from the beginning of the list and enqueuing items at the end of the list. Imo, suggesting something like this in an interview would cause you to look stupid. It would appear as if you do not know what queue functionality is, and that you think that if a data structure is not called a queue, it is not a queue. In java, in fact, a LinkedList is a queue (implements the queue interface).